# How do you get an element with data- attr with cypress

Tags: cypress

Im trying to test click and drag on a `<g/ >` html element with Cypress. This element have an unique data-shapes, so I used `cy.get('[data-shapes= "vauleA valueB valueC"]')`

For the drag and drop I tried `.trigger('mousedown', {clientX, clientY})`, but nothing happens. Actually, I realize that cypress does get the element when I run the test, but ignores it. Even a simple `.click()` method on the element does not work when testing.

Code right now:

```
cy.wait(2000)
cy.get('g[data-shapes="c-block c-2 end"]').click()
```

[This is the test result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whtEE.png)

[This is what I expect to output at least with click() method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmdcU.png)

Comment: There's an open issue on their github related to this https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/695 Adding `.click({force: true})` may work

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: Did you click that step on the left side (where it does the click)? When you click or hover on it, it'll show you the snapshot. What you're seeing in the UI might be the last snapshot after it's been clicked